# How to match these words in regex?

Tags: regex, string

I want to match all these using 1 single regex code.
 https://regex.alf.nu/4
I wrote this ([a-z]{2})(\w+)?\1 but its not working

1. anallagmatic
2. bassarisk
3. abba
4. chorioallantois
5. coccomyces
6. commotive
7. engrammatic
8. glossoscopia
9. hexacoralla
10. hippogriffin
11. inflammableness
12. otto
13. overattached
14. saffarid
15. sarraceniaceae
16. scillipicrin
17. tlapallan
18. trillion
19. unclassably
20. unfitting
21. unsmelled
22. warrandice

Comment: `(firststring|secondstring|......|laststring)`

Comment: I want to write small code not in or format first string or 2nd or 3rd

Comment: The only common part I see here is that there is at least a pair of the same letter.

Comment: Pls add some explanation.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, Dont know why people are marking it as duplicate :(

Comment: @andrahul ya, at first I don't see anything other than "I want to match all with a single regex". SO always try to show your attempts at very first.

Comment: Now, I'm going to reopen this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the *opposite* of the regex golf question you linked.  The shortest answer I can come up with to match all of those words (and none of the other set of words) is:

```
(.)(.)\2\1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\b\w*(.)(.)\2\1\w*\b
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/eipcCbBLCh)